# How to down convert KeePass .kdbx to .kdb

Tags: keepass

I want to down convert my KeePass .kdbx file to a .kdb file because I want to be able to open it with KeePassX (OS X version), which only supports .kdb

I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

Comment: Is the original kdbx file used on windows or another operating system? If you use windows, simply do what @JChristian answered, otherwise edit your question to include the OS you have access to

Comment: KeePassX 2 Alpha works perfectly fine and handles the kdbx format.

Answer (score 10):

Just go to File->Export and you should have the option to export to a .kdb file.

Comment: noteworthy to add that this will only work on windows though.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

On OSX and Linux distros you might not be able to export to .kdb, getting this dreadful error:
[image]

### What I did

I've forked [`lastpass2keepass`](https://github.com/anirudhjoshi/lastpass2keepass) into [`csv2keepass`](https://github.com/asfaltboy/csv2keepass) and it now supports csv files exported from KeePass 2.0.

### Solution (which also works in linux!)

To export to csv, just go into KeePass 2.0, open your `db.kdbx` file and do

```
File --> Export --> KeePass CSV (1.x)
```

Now run the python script:

```
python csv2keepass.py exportedCSVFile
```

After that to import do

```
File --> Import from... --> KeePassX XML (*.xml)
```

Comment: I wonder if you would be able to run Keepass 2.x under Wine instead of Mono - and if that would allow conversion to the older format.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use:

https://github.com/dvorka/keepass2-to-keepassx

for conversion of the KeePass2 password database to KeePassX. It's done via XML export/import of both tools.

Comment: Just a note; "You must have Java Runtime Environment (JRE) installed."

Answer (score 0):

#### Try *KeePassX 2 (Alpha)* as suggested by Daniel B,

> www.keepassx.org/news/2013/03/393 worked for me.
>
> (If someone with the reputation wants to make this a link, please do.)

#### run it in a Windows VM, or

> Download the ["Professional" (2.n) Windows version of KeePass](http://keepass.info/download.html), and run it in a Windows VM. You can shared the file either through a VM-runner-host shared folder (let VirtualBox or VMWare do the magic for you), or you can share the file through a networked drive.
>
> Once you have the file in windows you can either export the v2 file to a v1 type, or make a habit of starting the VM to modify KeePass (in which case I would recommend suspending/pausing the VM rather than shutting it down).

#### attempt to run it using Mono.

> There is a [recommendation buried in the KeePass.info site](http://keepass.info/download/p_macosx/index.html) to use Mono and XQuartz, to support the .NET dependencies with free and many-system-compatible libraries. I had less than complete success with this method, possibly due to the version of OSX I'm running, 10.7.5. The application would open, but before it offered a database selection and password window, would suddenly close and generate an Apple error report.

...if you cannot re-export it in the v1 format from a Windows system.